# Copying a local file from Mac to an ssh session in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ssh

I'm new to using bash commands and having some trouble. I'm ssh'ing into a linux box which contains some of my work files. I have a local file on my mac which I need to copy onto the server.

Here are the steps I've gone through so far:
1) ssh usrname@orgname.edu
2) Entered password 
3) pwd 
4) working directory: home/usrname

I'm stuck after this. I have a local folder in documents in my mac. I want to copy it to my working directory on the server I"m ssh'ed into.

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: use `scp` instead.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. SuperUser.com is a better place for technical support questions.

Answer (score 54):

When you ssh to a remote machine, then it's as if you are sitting in front of that other machine and execute commands in it. While you are in that state, you cannot copy file to (or from) it. Instead you have to use a different tool, `scp`, which also belongs in the `ssh` family and in fact calls `ssh` behind the scenes. This is how you copy a local directory to a remote machine:

```
scp -rp /path/to/local/dir usrname@orgname.edu:/path/to/remote/dir
```

I used the `-r` mode (which stands for recursive) to copy the directory recursively. See also the [manual of scp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html) for more details

Comment: What if my VM has an adress that is like this ubuntu@ip ?

Answer (score 21):

You will want to use `sftp`instead of `ssh` for this. Try the following:

1. `sftp usrname@orgname.edu`
2. Enter password
3. `cd <directory where you want to transfer the file>`
4. `put <name of file you want to transfer>`

You can also add 'l' before some commands to indicate that you want to do that locally. i.e. `ls` will display files on the remote server, and `lls` will display files on the local machine.

**EDIT :**

You will want to make sure that you either

a. navigate to the folder that contains the file you want to transfer prior to starting the sftp process.

b. use `lcd` and `lls` once you are in the sftp session to navigate to the local folder that contains the file you want to transfer.

As mentioned in the comments, using the full path to the file you want to transfer doesn't work.

Comment: I get a message saying there is no such file or directory when I put the full path of the file on my local machine I want to transfer

Comment: Good point. I just tried it and it appears that using the full path doesn't work. You would want to use 'lcd' and 'lls' to make sure you are in the correct folder then. I will change my answer to include that. Thanks ixbo45.

Answer (score 1):

From your Linux command prompt: `scp -C -r username@remote.host:/path/to/remote/directory/ target/directory`

Comment: scp pathToFileOnMBP username@linuxHost:pathToFileOnLinux